# Properties of integrals

Tags: integration

How do I prove that the integral of a product is not equal to the product of integrals?

$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x)dx \neq \left(\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx\right)\left(\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx\right)
$

Comment: Find an example of specific numbers $a$ and $b$ and specific functions $f$ and $g$ for which the two expressions are not equal.

Comment: Is there a more general proof, or is proof by contradiction sufficient?

Comment: They're almost never equal.  Pick numbers $a$ and $b$ and functions $f$ and $g$ at random and the two sides will probably be different.  Yes, one counterexample suffices.

Comment: @user115235 Finding one counterexample is general. It means the statement doesn't always hold.

Answer (score 5):

$\displaystyle \left(\int_0^2 1\ dx\right)\left(\int_0^2 1\ dx\right) = 2\cdot 2 = 4 \neq 2 = \int_0^2 \left(1\cdot 1\right)\ dx$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x) = g(x) = 1,$ and $b-a \neq 1.$ See what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a = 0, b = 1, f(x) = x, g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. What is $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx$?  What "is" $\displaystyle \int_a^bf(x)dx\int_a^bg(x)dx$?